# Constraining an IDW interpolation

Tags: inverse-distance-weighted

I am running an IDW on a data set that represents point values of water current speed. I would like to run the IDW only within the water area of another shapefile that shows the shape of the water body. So far I have only been able to keep the IDW to the XY extents (a square) of the data points, not within the waterbody shape. Any ideas about how to do this would be very helpful

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Run IDW and get results in the XY extent as before, and then clip the  output with your water body.  Seem like this should get you what you are after.